# Run a function user by user

Tags: meteor

I want to run a function on each user.
I know how to target a user logged in (`this.userId` client-side or `Meteor.userId` server-side) but not all the users - regardless they are logged in or not.

The idea is to check if a `date type` field (`profile.Actu`), so in the profile user schema, is passed by more than 15 days. If yes, send a mail to a `profile.recipients` (also a field (`email type`) in the profile.user schema.

Then I will run this function by a cron task, like every day, on each user, in order to check if that function must send a mail if the date (`profile.Actu`) is, that day, passed... Hope you understand the idea.

Can anyone help me ? I'm very new to meteor, so my question may look naive... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run this on the server. There is a method called

```
Meteor.users()
```

Which will return you a list of all the users, which you iterate over. http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users

If you want to do this on a regular basis, you should use a package like synced-cron https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron to do the job.

and in case you need a reference for sending emails, look here http://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this low level question - in a very complete way.

Comment: You are welcome, that's the idea of stack overflow, to provide well thought out answers. You marking the answer as correct is also valuable for future reference.